# Java - ProcessBuilder is not outputting my python file

Tags: java, file

Some context: I'm trying to make a GUI on java and have python code run once I click a button on the GUI. For example if I press start on the java GUI, it will run the python code on file .py.

Why is it not outputting anything? You can also try this by creating a test python file and just inputting your own file location into the code below.

Code so far:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class main_gui extends JFrame {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe",
                "cd \"G:\\...Javaa\\filetranslatorapplication\\file_translator_app.py");
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = builder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while (true) {
            line = r.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

**Two things to keep in mind:**

1. The python file in NOT in the same place as this java file.
2. The java file and python file are both on a usb, hence the "G:\..".

Also, if anyone has a better way of running python code through java gui, please feel free to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Why don't you try jython?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd",
            "/c \"G: && python Javaa\\filetranslatorapplication\\file_translator_app.py\"");
```

This gets executed when I run my Java application from a different drive. But, for you, if it is the same drive, need not switch to `G:`. You may execute the py file with `python` command.

Comment: It worked once, but then after that it didn't work anymore. Have you tried running it more than once?

Comment: How can it work only once! :D You may check the output from the process. Is there any lock on file or something?

Comment: hmm yes it does seem strange, i'll have to probably do some debugging on my end. Thank you for a solution though! Would you happen to know how to use jython on pycharm? I have already downloaded and installed jython.

Comment: Plenty of problem in this approach. 1. if you want to have current working directory set to `g:`, there are better way in ProcessBuilder other than doing a strange `g: && command`. 2. `python` should accept full path (include `g:\...`) for the location of script, so you don't need to do the weird `g: && command`  3. If you have multiple arguments for the command, simply split into separate arguments to `ProcessBuilder`.  You don't need to make a loooong string (and do the quoting) as single argument.

Answer (score 0):

Your process simply does not make sense.

It simply spawn a `cmd`, and `cd` to an invalid directory (as it is a file).

What you want is probably

```
cmd /c python g:\your\path\foo.py
```

or

```
cmd /c g:\your\path\foo.py
```

or simply

```
may\be\full\path\is\needed\python g:\your\path\foo.py
```

So, your code should look like:

```
ProcessBuilder builder 
    = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "python", "g:\\yourpath\\file_translator_app.py");
// or 
// = new ProcessBuilder("python", "g:\\yourpath\\file_translator_app.py");
// or 
// = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "g:\\yourpath\\file_translator_app.py");
```